# Editable dropdown is not clearing another dropdown text on select event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

Hello I am using jquery editable dropdownlist where i can both select and type in the dropdownlist to perform autocomplete also.What I want ,to clear the second editable dropdown  selected/input text(only) on changing the first editable dropdown .I just want to clear the text only(not selected options) in second dropdownlist so that i could select/type a new item in it .

I have used the below code for change event its working but the text is still there.I just want to remove the second dropdown text only .

```
 $("#sel1").combobox({
            select: function (event, ui) {  
               $("#sel2").text('');
            }
        });
```

the code is lengthy so i also added a fiddle below.Please let me know what can i do in this situation if it is possible and how?.Or it can be done in another way
**I am strucked in this problem for last 2 days**  Please help needed.
 please see the below fiddle you will get more clear.Thanks for the help.

[**clear editable dropdown text only FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/n562jp5L/5/)

Comment: Do you just want to clear the editable field of the second dropdown? Or also remove some or all options from it?

Comment: no i just want to clear the field only the options will be same. i know there are some problems in my code but cant find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the editable field :

```
$("#sel2").next().find("input").val('');
```

Why? Because this editable field is an `input` injected by jQuery-UI.
And it is located in the "next" element (from the select point of view) as a child.

Here is your [**Fiddle updated**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/edp9kz7a/).

Comment: thank you very much its the next() i was missing .I tried using only find(). Thank you very much . :)

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your select box problem, but you have some other things going on in your code that might be breaking things.

```
  $("#sel1").change(function () {       
    $("#sel2").prepend('<option value=""></option>'); //trying to clear the second dropdown textonly 
    $("#sel2 option[value='']").attr('selected', true);
   });
```

Comment: i tried this befor didn't work. i know there are some problems in my code but cant solve  it

Comment: right, but that works above. I tested it. If it's not working for you then you need to fix the other errors first. are you using some kind of plugin? I got an error for $.widget

Comment: yes i ised jquery ui. .  and also some extra code you will find in the fiddle